# Sequence increasing and inequality.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Suppose that $\{a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing non-negative sequence and suppose that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L<\infty.$$
Let $\epsilon\in (0,1).$

Now, it is easy to guess the following: if we take $(1-\varepsilon)L$, exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$a_n\ge(1-\varepsilon)L\quad\text{for all}\;n>m.$$

My problem is to write in a formal way that I just said.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Take a good look at the formal definition of "$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$". It will guide you.

Comment: Note that if $L=0$, the conclusion is not true. For example, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: @xpaul Does your sequence admit limit?

Comment: @JackJ., the limit is $0$.

Comment: @xpaul Ok. Can you help me, I still haven't been able to show what I said, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of limits, for $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, there is $N>0$ such that, if $n>N$, then
$$ |a_n-L|<\epsilon L $$
or 
$$ -\epsilon L<a_n-L<\epsilon L. $$
Using this part
$$ -\epsilon L<a_n-L $$
you will get the conclusion that, for $n>N$,
$$ a_n>(1-\epsilon)L. $$

Comment: Note that in the statement $a_n$ is not negative, therefore the results is true also for $L=0$, or not?

Comment: If $L=0$, the result is not true, For example, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: Your $a_n$ is not non negative!

Comment: $L>0$ is important. Another example, $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{n}, a_{2n-1}=0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. You can't obtain $a_n>0$ for $n>N$ (some $N>0$).

Comment: Thanks, but $\ge$ is true, if $a_n$ is not negative, right?

Comment: If $L=0$ it is always true that $a_n\ge (1-\epsilon) L=0$ for all $n$, since $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$. Or not?

Comment: If the strict inequality $>$ is required, $L>0$ is necessary.

Comment: I did not see that "$\{a_n\}$ is a non-negative sequence".